# Spotbugs to find bugs in java file

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

Currently we are running spot bugs against jars to find the bugs. Is there any way to run spotbugs over a single java file to find the list of bugs in it

Answer (score 1):

A quick search gave me the following link. https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html.
I didn't get a chance to test it out, but from what I read, it looks like you can supply an XML configuration file where you would filter in only the class you need.
The below snippet must work.

```
<Match>
   <Class name="com.foobar.MyClass" />
</Match>
```

However if you are looking for static code analysis on demand, you could just install the findbugs plugin on intellij and use it on demand

Answer (score 0):

Spotbugs works with compiled Java files. That means it analizes .class files which exist in .jar files.

It's not possible to analize the java files without compiling them first.